# $_POST и циклы в PHP

Tags: post, php, mysql

Как правильно вытащить циклом значения из POST-массива, если внутри POST есть несколько массивов.
Пример массива пост:

```
Array
(
[WT_TD_] => Array
    (
        [1] => Ð”ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»ÑŒ1
        [2] => Ð”ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»ÑŒ2
        [3] => Ð”ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»ÑŒ3
    )
[WT_A_] => Array
    (
        [1] => 25
        [2] => 24
        [3] => 2
    )

[WT_B_] => Array
    (
        [1] => 25
        [2] => 24
        [3] => 424
    )
}
```

Соответственно нужен цикл, который будет вытаскивать каждое первое значение каждого массива, потом каждое 2 и так далее.
Как правильно определить счётчик в этом случае?
Делаю так:

```
$i = 1;
while($i <= 50)
{
if (isset($_POST['WT_DT_[$i]']))    {$WT_DT = $_POST['WT_DT_[$i]']; if ($WT_DT == '') {unset($WT_DT);}}
if (isset($_POST['WT_A_[$i]'])) {$WT_A = $_POST['WT_A_[$i]']; if ($WT_A == '') {unset($WT_A);}}
if (isset($_POST['WT_B_[$i]'])) {$WT_B = $_POST['WT_B_[$i]']; if ($WT_B == '') {unset($WT_B);}}
//Запись данных в базу, а потом:
$i++;
}
```

Предполагаю, что неправильно обозначаю это место:

```
(isset($_POST['WT_DT_[$i]']))
```

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: [foreach][1]?


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А как через POST можно такой массив получить не понимаю, взгляните на нижний код может поможет

```
$r = array(
    'a' => array(
        'a_1' => 'Один',
        'a_2' => 'Два',
        'a_3' => 'Три',
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'b_4' => 'Четыре',
        'b_5' => 'Пять',
        'b_6' => 'Шесть',
    ),
    'с' => array(
        'с_7' => 'Семь',
        'с_8' => 'Восемь',
        'с_9' => 'Девять',
    ),        
);

$i = 0;

$keys = array_keys($r);
$result = array();

foreach ($r as $item)
{
    $result[$keys[$i]] = $item;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: ну как, можно...
<input name="WT_TD_[]" />

Comment: совсем забыл спасибо

Comment: Получается, что мне нужно перегруппировать массивы по такому принципу:

Массив А должен содержать в себе а_1, b_1 и c_1
Массив B - a_2, b_2, c_2

и тд. Как это сделать?
Первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой

Comment: выше написанный код разве не делает этого?